# How to execute command "wm size" in Android Runtime?

Tags: android, exec

I try to execute a command `wm` for change the display resolution of the device. If I run the command in **ADB SHELL works perfect**, but when I try to do in code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wm size 1080x1920");
```

nothing happens. The *logcat* shows:

```
? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.wm.Wm
? I/art: System.exit called, status: 1
? I/AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 1.
```

Comment: I doubt that is possible, except perhaps on a rooted device, and then only if you execute that command with superuser privileges.

Comment: @CommonsWare I think `wm` command is not neccesary root. I will try with  a root runtime... thanks!

Comment: Yes @CommonsWare I use a root runtime execution and works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most `adb shell` commands require above-average privileges. When running those commands through `adb shell`, you get those privileges. When running those commands directly from an app, you do not... unless the device is rooted and you arrange to run those commands as a superuser.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare is neccesary use a root device.