# How to change display resolution using ADB or programmatically?

Tags: android, adb, android-tv

I want to know, how to change display resolution and also refresh rate in Android Box or TV. I've tried using below script throught ADB. Lets say I want to change the display resolution from 1920x1080 to 1280x720:

```
wm size 1280x720
wm density 160
```

The resolution is successfully changed, but Android still reads resolution as 1920x1080, even after restart. As shown in the picture below :

[screen_resolution_in_android_settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqbtX.jpg)

Have I missed something or is there another method to change default screen resolution?

Comment: As far as I know, you need root the device.

Comment: Yes the device is already root, but what i need to do then?

Comment: Your question is similar to: [How can I set a custom screen resolution for my Android TV box?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/144978/3573) Regardless you should explain  how you are testing (name of TV box, OS version, TV/monitor name/model number).

Comment: @MorrisonChang yes it's very similar, but the answer on that post is just same like i did on my explanation above, they use adb shell wm size and adb shell wm density which not worked.

Comment: Manufacturers can customize Android which is why I asked for identifying what hardware/OS version you are using to test. Both for others to try if they have similar hardware and for future readers encountering the same problem.

Comment: Why don't you save the size and load the saved size and change the screen size after launch then?

Comment: @Morrison Cheng i used device TX3 Mini with OS Android 7.

Comment: @c-an It's not for my personal use and this is a unique case, i need to change screen resolution through ADB or programatically using JAVA / Kotlin.

Comment: You can do it through shell.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36117004/how-to-execute-command-wm-size-in-android-runtime

Comment: @c-an I've checked the URL that you suggested above, but still the command "wm size 1080x1920" didn't worked, because i've also tried it before.

Comment: Do any other shell commands work? Then, It should work.

Comment: @c-an I am sorry what i mean "didn't worked" is that "wm size" command not solving my issue, the command itself is worked properly.